# iOS Present Popover from bar button item bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uipopover

I have an `UIPopoverController` that presents an `UIViewController` using this method:

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.infoBarButtonItem 
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                     animated:YES];
```

`self.popover` is my `UIPopoverController`.

The code works well, but the Popover arrow is  in the middle of the `BarButtonItem` how do I display the Popover with its arrow "under" the button?

This is what it currently looks like:
[image: altText]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = self.infoBarButtonItem ;

UIView *view = [item valueForKey:@"view"];

if(view){

        CGRect frame=view.frame;

        [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:frame
                                      inView:view.superview
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                    animated:YES];



}
```

Comment: How would you get the frame of a UIBarButtonItem??

Answer (score 16):

In iOS 9 you can try this code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
alert.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to format your code snippets using a 4-space indent, to make it look nicer.

Comment: @StudentT Sorry that's a UIAlertController. Answer edited.

Comment: As of this writing, note that the `barButtonItem` property of a `UIPopoverPresentationController` is deprecated in iOS 16. You should switch to `sourceItem` if possible. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622314-barbuttonitem

Answer (score 4):

For all who are using `UIViewController` with `PopoverPresentationController` (iOS 9+);
This worked for me:
you can directly set your `UIBarButtonItem` like this.

```
myPopoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = myUIBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use the method:

```
presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```

and give it an appropriate CGRect to make the `UIPopoverController` appear where you would like.

You could then specify exactly where you'd like the popover to originate and point to. This is not an ideal situation, but when it come to giving the popover controller a `UIBarButtonItem`, you have no say as to how it should use it to position itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the selector method of the info button :

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame]
                                         inView:self.view
                       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                       animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: It's `UIBarButtonItem`, not `UIButton`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using this code.

**In Swift**

```
 if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    let item = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    let view = item?.value(forKey: "view")
    let popPresenter = alert.popoverPresentationController
    popPresenter?.sourceView = view
    popPresenter?.sourceRect = view.bounds
 }
 present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**In Objective-C**

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIBarButtonItem *item = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    UIView *view = [item valueForKey:@"view"];
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = alert.popoverPresentationController;
    if(view){
       popover.sourceRect = view.frame;
       popover.sourceView = view;
    }
 }
```